# Django order query by foreign key (reverse direction)

Tags: python, mysql, django

i' ve 2 simple models, like this:

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    ...
```

and

```
class Objdata(models.Model):
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj)
    ...
    datum = models.DateTimeField()
```

. My goal would be to select all Objs based on the belonging Objdata' s latest datum entry.

Maybe it' s already too complicated for django, however on sql side it' s not that very complicated to query it.

So, is there a Django way to achieve this, or how would be the best(?) to implement it. My solution is a bit complicated at the moment.

---

A small pseudocode might help what i want to achieve:

```
lst = []
for elem in Obj.objects.filter():
    try:
        lst.append((elem.objdata_set.all().order_by('-datum')[0].datum, elem))
    except:
        lst.append((elem.datum, elem))
res = [e[1] for e in sorted(lst, reverse = True)]
```

Comment: You'll have to explain further. What does "select all Objs based on the belonging Objdata's latest datum entry" mean? (I realize English is not your first language.) Do you perhaps mean you want to get the latest Objdata for each Obj?

Comment: You' re right about my english :- ). I updated my question with an additional pseudo code what i would like to achieve. As a result i don' t want to get Objdatas, but i want to get Objs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you just want to get all Objs, sorted by their latest Objdata.datum. You can do that with aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Max
objs = Obj.objects.annotate(latest_data=Max('objdata__datum')).order_by('latest_data')
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i want. The result is slightly different from mine as it handles differently the case when obj.objdata_set.all().count == 0, but this is even better. Thanks for it!

Comment: Oh, ok, done, i didn' t know there' s this possibility, but now i can see the green tick :- ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly try this:

```
objdates = Objdate.objects.order_by('obj_id', '-dateum').distinct('obj_id').select_related('obj')
objs = [objdate.obj for objdate in objdates]
```

Comment: Don't forget to put `.select_related('obj')` in there. Saves you a query for each `Objdate` instance you get.

Comment: @knbk thanks for your comment. I didn't know `.select_related` before but it is good. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you think Django's model query is too much or not enough to achieve what you want, or you'd prefer to SQL (*however on sql side it' s not that very complicated to query it*), you can use **raw** [READ MORE HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries):

```
Obj.objects.raw('SELECT ... your SQL statement here;')
```

This will return a **model instance**, you can also perform custom SQL directly using **connection** [READ HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Yes, thanks, i know, just i wanted a djangonic way :- ).

Comment: @user2194805, this is perhaps the most efficient and fastest **djangoic** way because custom SQL avoids django's model layer. Even **raw** will perform better than normal Django lazy **QuerySet**. Many django apps (performance required) usually ends up using raw SQL.

Comment: @Anzel That's bogus. The ORM has almost no overhead compared to `raw()` (less than 5% for a single-row pk lookup, less than 0.5% for a more expensive lookup of multiple ordered objects). Direct use of `connection.cursor()` provides a performance increase at the cost of development speed and all ORM features that a lot of Django depends on. To bypass a large part of the Django framework for a negligible performance boost is certainly _not_ pythonic imho. I simply cannot see any but the most performance-critical apps using raw sql over the ORM for any queries that the ORM can reasonably handle.

Comment: @knbk, it's a fair point, but to consider if you have multiple tables with several related fields, the overhead becomes much more expensive. Raw / custom SQL gives an edge over ORM for not to hitting the database/table multiple times, although crafting careful query may help but it certainly at the same time increases the cost of development. And remember, many developers are actually feel more comfortable to write SQL statements.

Comment: @Anzel The ORM does _not_ hit the table/database more than raw sql, unless you completely ignore the most basic of optimizations. Multiple databases are the exception, but that's only really applicable if your site is part of a larger project. I can see where it has its uses, and even why some developers would prefer raw SQL, but that doesn't make it pythonic and I would certainly not recommend it to people who don't absolutely need it. Raw SQL also opens you up to [SQL injection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) if you're not careful enough.

Comment: @knbk, sure but OP's asking for Django way, not Pythonic. And for the django applications I've worked with before which required optimization, I'd say > 95% ends up using **raw** or custom SQL at some points. I do understand where your points are coming from, I'm not arguing but this is quite honestly what I believe in.